# Display title property of html anchor on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor

I use a very simple

```
<a title="This Text is shown in a bubble">[?]</a>
```

to display a help-button that pops up a help text in a bubble on hover.

I do not need the link (as seen above, I don't specify a href property), but most browsers hide the tooltip when you click the link, which is not what I want.

Is there a way to display the text on hover AND on click? Possibly with Javascript or maybe even purely with CSS? Or is it possible to create the behaviour with jQuery or similar?

Comment: There are many plugins available which use jQuery, however to try and change the default behavior of when a title is triggered for displaying is not possible.

Comment: For an easy solution, you can check:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Comment: <span title="my text">[?]</span> ?

Answer (score 2):

There's a way to do this purely with CSS. It might not completely suit your needs, but you'd be setting your text in an adjacent `span` which you can style to your heart's content and using the `:focus` state of the `a` element to toggle its visibility.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;  
}
a + span {
  display: none;
}
a:focus + span, a:hover + span {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">[?]</a><span>Hello</span>
```